# "fitBounds" Google Maps and Places API Not Working

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, initialization

Purpose: The goal of this code is to give user the ability to search a location and the map zoom into the given location area.

Problem: In the search bar you can type an address.. google places suggestions will auto populate and user can select a location.. however after selection google maps does not zoom in to designated area.. it remains zoomed on default area.

Note: I've been told that within the init() function the "fitBounds" is not relating to the code, but when i tried changing the code to the following.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
```

the map no longer displays at all. how can i fix this problem?

Source Code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="mapsearch">Location</label>
                                            <div class="input-group location">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mapsearch" placeholder="Enter Location">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker geolocation" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Find my position"></i></span>
                                            </div>
  </div>
                                        <!-- /.form-group -->


  <div class="map"  id='mapkit-2243'>

        <script> 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
var map, markersArray = [];

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, location) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        function close(location) {
            location.ib.close();
            location.infoWindowVisible = false;
            location.ib = null;
        }

        if (location.infoWindowVisible === true) {
            close(location);
        } else {
            markersArray.forEach(function(loc, index){
                if (loc.ib && loc.ib !== null) {
                    close(loc);
                }
            });

            var boxText = document.createElement('div');
            boxText.style.cssText = 'background: #fff;';
            boxText.classList.add('md-whiteframe-2dp');

            function buildPieces(location, el, part, icon) {
                if (location[part] === '') {
                    return '';
                } else if (location.iw[part]) {
                    switch(el){
                        case 'photo':
                            if (location.photo){
                                return '<div class="iw-photo" style="background-image: url(' + location.photo + ');"></div>';
                             } else {
                                return '';
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'iw-toolbar':
                            return '<div class="iw-toolbar"><h3 class="md-subhead">' + location.title + '</h3></div>';
                            break;
                        case 'div':
                            switch(part){
                                case 'email':
                                    return '<div class="iw-details"><i class="material-icons" style="color:#4285f4;"><img src="//cdn.mapkit.io/v1/icons/' + icon + '.svg"/></i><span><a href="mailto:' + location.email + '" target="_blank">' + location.email + '</a></span></div>';
                                    break;
                                case 'web':
                                    return '<div class="iw-details"><i class="material-icons" style="color:#4285f4;"><img src="//cdn.mapkit.io/v1/icons/' + icon + '.svg"/></i><span><a href="' + location.web + '" target="_blank">' + location.web_formatted + '</a></span></div>';
                                    break;
                                case 'desc':
                                    return '<label class="iw-desc" for="cb_details"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_details"/><h3 class="iw-x-details">Details</h3><i class="material-icons toggle-open-details"><img src="//cdn.mapkit.io/v1/icons/' + icon + '.svg"/></i><p class="iw-x-details">' + location.desc + '</p></label>';
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return '<div class="iw-details"><i class="material-icons"><img src="//cdn.mapkit.io/v1/icons/' + icon + '.svg"/></i><span>' + location[part] + '</span></div>';
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'open_hours':
                            var items = '';
                            if (location.open_hours.length > 0){
                                for (var i = 0; i < location.open_hours.length; ++i) {
                                    if (i !== 0){
                                        items += '<li><strong>' + location.open_hours[i].day + '</strong><strong>' + location.open_hours[i].hours +'</strong></li>';
                                    }
                                    var first = '<li><label for="cb_hours"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_hours"/><strong>' + location.open_hours[0].day + '</strong><strong>' + location.open_hours[0].hours +'</strong><i class="material-icons toggle-open-hours"><img src="//cdn.mapkit.io/v1/icons/keyboard_arrow_down.svg"/></i><ul>' + items + '</ul></label></li>';
                                }
                                return '<div class="iw-list"><i class="material-icons first-material-icons" style="color:#4285f4;"><img src="//cdn.mapkit.io/v1/icons/' + icon + '.svg"/></i><ul>' + first + '</ul></div>';
                             } else {
                                return '';
                            }
                            break;
                     }
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }

            boxText.innerHTML = 
                buildPieces(location, 'photo', 'photo', '') +
                buildPieces(location, 'iw-toolbar', 'title', '') +
                buildPieces(location, 'div', 'address', 'location_on') +
                buildPieces(location, 'div', 'web', 'public') +
                buildPieces(location, 'div', 'email', 'email') +
                buildPieces(location, 'div', 'tel', 'phone') +
                buildPieces(location, 'div', 'int_tel', 'phone') +
                buildPieces(location, 'open_hours', 'open_hours', 'access_time') +
                buildPieces(location, 'div', 'desc', 'keyboard_arrow_down');

            var myOptions = {
                alignBottom: true,
                content: boxText,
                disableAutoPan: true,
                maxWidth: 0,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -40),
                zIndex: null,
                boxStyle: {
                    opacity: 1,
                    width: '280px'
                },
                closeBoxMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px',
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
                isHidden: false,
                pane: 'floatPane',
                enableEventPropagation: false
            };

            location.ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
            location.ib.open(map, marker);
            location.infoWindowVisible = true;
        }
    });
}

function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.796154069254015,-96.80221670166623),
        zoom: 19,
        gestureHandling: 'auto',
        fullscreenControl: true,
        zoomControl: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable : true,
        clickableIcons: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [{"stylers":[{"hue":"#B61530"},{"saturation":60},{"lightness":-40}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"color":"#B61530"}]},{"featureType":"road","stylers":[{"color":"#B61530"},{}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"color":"#B61530"},{"lightness":6}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"color":"#B61530"},{"lightness":-25}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"color":"#B61530"},{"lightness":-10}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"color":"#B61530"},{"lightness":70}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","stylers":[{"color":"#B61530"},{"lightness":90}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]}]
    }
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('mapkit-2243');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    var locations = [
        {"title":"American Airlines Center","address":"2500 Victory Ave, Dallas, TX 75219, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7905064,"lng":-96.8103549,"vicinity":"2500 Victory Ave, Dallas, TX 75219, United States","open_hours":"","marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Avenu Lounge","address":"2912 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.8001166,"lng":-96.80059410000001,"vicinity":"2912 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Bombshells - Dallas","address":"7501 N Stemmons Fwy, Dallas, TX 75247, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.820152,"lng":-96.870677,"vicinity":"7501 N Stemmons Fwy, Dallas, TX 75247, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Circo Texas","address":"2619 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.797091,"lng":-96.801943,"vicinity":"2619 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":"","marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Clutch Bar and Restaurant","address":"2520 Cedar Springs Rd, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7988131,"lng":-96.80514870000002,"vicinity":"2520 Cedar Springs Rd, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Concrete Cowboy","address":"2512 Cedar Springs Rd, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7983882,"lng":-96.80525010000002,"vicinity":"2512 Cedar Springs Rd, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"District","address":"1520 Main St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.780521,"lng":-96.798631,"vicinity":"1520 Main St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Fat Rabbit","address":"2533 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7962824,"lng":-96.80203640000002,"vicinity":"2533 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Frankie's - Downtown","address":"1303 Main St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7804885,"lng":-96.8006992,"vicinity":"1303 Main St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Hard Rock Cafe","address":"2211 N Houston St, Dallas, TX 75219, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.78461349999999,"lng":-96.80912119999999,"vicinity":"2211 N Houston St, Dallas, TX 75219, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Harwood International","address":"14, 2501 N Harwood St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7916813,"lng":-96.80628179999997,"vicinity":"14, 2501 N Harwood St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":"","marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Havana Social Club","address":"3030 Olive St, Dallas, TX 75219, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7895073,"lng":-96.80912089999998,"vicinity":"3030 Olive St, Dallas, TX 75219, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"House of Blues","address":"2200 N Lamar St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7850366,"lng":-96.80824989999996,"vicinity":"2200 N Lamar St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Illume Nightclub","address":"1015 Elm St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7807779,"lng":-96.803675,"vicinity":"1015 Elm St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Jakes Burgers and Beer","address":"2702 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7974859,"lng":-96.80119760000002,"vicinity":"2702 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Kung Fu Saloon","address":"2911 Routh St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7991499,"lng":-96.8052174,"vicinity":"2911 Routh St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Level","address":"3005 Routh St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7993978,"lng":-96.8056105,"vicinity":"3005 Routh St, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Masque","address":"2533 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7962967,"lng":-96.80208959999999,"vicinity":"2533 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"McKinney Avenue Tavern","address":"2822 Mc Kinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.79928419999999,"lng":-96.80066369999997,"vicinity":"2822 Mc Kinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Medusa Dallas","address":"1930 Pacific Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7828849,"lng":-96.79473080000002,"vicinity":"1930 Pacific Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Nickel And Rye","address":"2523 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.796114,"lng":-96.80220029999998,"vicinity":"2523 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Punk Society","address":"752261533, 2723 Elm St, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.784821,"lng":-96.783792,"vicinity":"752261533, 2723 Elm St, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Quill Kitchen + Cocktails","address":"1628 Oak Lawn Ave #100, Dallas, TX 75207, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7971327,"lng":-96.81936359999997,"vicinity":"1628 Oak Lawn Ave #100, Dallas, TX 75207, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Sandbar Cantina And Grill","address":"317 S 2nd Ave, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7835101,"lng":-96.7742619,"vicinity":"317 S 2nd Ave, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Sidebar","address":"2626 Howell St #100, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7986114,"lng":-96.8027884,"vicinity":"2626 Howell St #100, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Sisu","address":"2508 Maple Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7950418,"lng":-96.80349419999999,"vicinity":"2508 Maple Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Status NightClub","address":"2019 N Lamar St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7836542,"lng":-96.80748240000003,"vicinity":"2019 N Lamar St, Dallas, TX 75202, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Taboo Lounge Dallas","address":"1418 N Riverfront Blvd, Dallas, TX 75207, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.790672,"lng":-96.82028300000002,"vicinity":"1418 N Riverfront Blvd, Dallas, TX 75207, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Tacos & Tequila","address":"2800 Routh St #155, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7989161,"lng":-96.80311460000001,"vicinity":"2800 Routh St #155, Dallas, TX 75201, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Tate's","address":"2723 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7986306,"lng":-96.80134950000001,"vicinity":"2723 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"The Bomb Factory","address":"2713 Canton St, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7821473,"lng":-96.78413639999997,"vicinity":"2713 Canton St, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","open_hours":"","marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"The Den","address":"2710 Mc Kinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7978287,"lng":-96.8010233,"vicinity":"2710 Mc Kinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"The Ginger Man","address":"2718 Boll St, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7982715,"lng":-96.80296120000003,"vicinity":"2718 Boll St, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Trees","address":"2709 Elm St, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.7846208,"lng":-96.7843848,"vicinity":"2709 Elm St, Dallas, TX 75226, United States","open_hours":"","marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}},{"title":"Trophy Room","address":"2714 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","desc":"","tel":"","int_tel":"","email":"","web":"","web_formatted":"","open":"","time":"","lat":32.797999,"lng":-96.8009912,"vicinity":"2714 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75204, United States","open_hours":[],"marker":"http://i.imgur.com/72aqKo5.png","iw":{"address":true,"desc":true,"email":true,"enable":true,"int_tel":true,"open":true,"open_hours":true,"photo":true,"tel":true,"title":true,"web":true}}
    ];
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: locations[i].marker,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i].title,
            address: locations[i].address,
            desc: locations[i].desc,
            tel: locations[i].tel,
            int_tel: locations[i].int_tel,
            vicinity: locations[i].vicinity,
            open: locations[i].open,
            open_hours: locations[i].open_hours,
            photo: locations[i].photo,
            time: locations[i].time,
            email: locations[i].email,
            web: locations[i].web,
            iw: locations[i].iw
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);

        if (locations[i].iw.enable === true){
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, locations[i]);
        }
    }
}


// search box 

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapsearch')); 


//place change event.. 

google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() { 

var places = searchBox.getPlaces (); 
var bounds= new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
var i, place; 

for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location); 
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location); 
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setZoom(15); 

});
```

```
        </div><!--/col-lg-4 -->


    </div><!-- /row -->
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask] for guidelines on how to write good Stack Overflow questions. In particular you should read [mcve]

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fitBounds' of undefined`, if I remove the `var` before `map`, it displays a map. Please provide a [mcve] (with the emphasis on **minimal**) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the map to zoom in on the area selected in the `SearchBox`, you need to write code to do that.  Currently the code adds changes the last marker's position to the location of the last result:

```
for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
}
```

Instead, I would suggest changing the location of the map to the suggested viewport of the first result.

```
map.fitBounds(places[0].geometry.viewport);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ctqakm8b/2/)

Comment: Thank You.. I'm trying to implement the code now, but It's not producing the same results as your proof of concept. Do I just delete the lines of code "for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);" and replace it with map.fitBounds(places[0].geometry.viewport); ? 

Note: I'm new to Google Maps API and Javascript

Comment: Hard to say what your problem is (as you didn't provide a [mcve] in your original question so I have no idea how my working example is different from your non-working one, could be that what I added to make it work fixed some other problem you have in your code)